# How to get dates based on current day in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get 4 different dates with PHP: 1 day, 1 week, 1 month and 3 months.
Every date is from the current day, so lets say today is 2014-11-26.

get past dates based on current date.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$one_day = $today - //how do I get yesterday from current day?
$one_week = $today -  //how do I get one week from current day?
$one month = $today - //how do I get one month from current day?
$three_month = $today -  //how do I get three month from current day?
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Half the trick here is [knowing what to search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+date+subtraction) (see the first result).

Comment: See the examples in [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)-function is perfect for that approach.
Use something like

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day"));
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 week"));
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month"));
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime('-1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime('-1 week');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime('-1 month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = new DateTime('-3 months');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

See [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for more details.